# Java 8 GroupingBy with Collectors on an object

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I would like to stream on a collection of object `myClass` in order to  grouping it using `Collectors.groupingBy()`. But, instead of retrieving a `Map<String, List<myClass>>`, I would like to group it on a object `myOutput` and retrieve a `Map<String, myOutput>`. I tried to create a custom collector :

```
List<myClass> myList = new ArrayList<myClass>();
myList.add(new myClass("a", 1));
myList.add(new myClass("a", 2));
myList.add(new myClass("b", 3));
myList.add(new myClass("b", 4));

Map<String,myOutput> myMap = myList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(myClass::getA, Collectors.of(myOutput::new, myOutput::accept, myOutput::combine)));
```

myClass :

```
protected String a;
protected int b;

public myClass(String aA, int aB)
{
  a = aA;
  b = aB;
}

public String getA()
{
  return a;
}

public int getB()
{
  return b;
}
```

myOutput :

```
protected int i;

public myOutput()
{
  i = 0;
}

public void accept(myClass aMyClass)
{
  i += aMyClass.getB();
}

public myOutput combine(myOutput aMyOutput)
{
  i += aMyOutput.getI();
  return this;
}

public int getI()
{
  return i;
}
```

But with this code, there is a problem with the collector :

```
Collectors.of(myOutput::new, myOutput::accept, myOutput::combine)
```

I know in this case a reduction will be much easier, but let's assume there are a lot of operation to do in the myOutput object.

What's wrong with this collector?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your collector is fine. You just need to have the [`Collector.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...-) static factory (and not `Collectors.of`).

This compiles fine and has the output you want

```
    Map<String,myOutput> myMap = 
        myList.stream()
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                myClass::getA, 
                Collector.of(myOutput::new, myOutput::accept, myOutput::combine)
              ));
```

Note, however, that you don't need such a collector. You can reuse an existing one. In this case, you want to group by the `a` value and for each element grouped to the same `a`, you want to sum their `b` value. You can use the built-in [`Collectors.summingInt(mapper)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) where the mapper returns the `b` value:

```
Map<String,Integer> myMap = 
    myList.stream()
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            myClass::getA, 
            Collectors.summingInt(myClass::getB)
          ));
```

Comment: Thanks. I was quite close :(  For sure the built-in summingInt collector would be a way better option in this case but I wanted to describe my issue with an understandable example. My needs required more complexes myClass and myOutput objects.